# How to update pager icons when using a timeout with jquery cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, cycle

Basically I've created a slideshow with jquery cycle, which has buttons and pager navigation - each time the 'next' or 'previous' button is pressed the pager is updated to represent which slide is being shown.
Now I want to add a timer to the slideshow and again update the pager navigation image to represent which slide is being shown.
I've tried using timeoutFn, but I haven't been able to get it to work.
Here is some of the code at the moment- I'm using a global variable 'currentBut' so i know which slide I'm currently on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentBut = "";
    var lastButIndex = 0;



    $('#slide').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollHorz',
    speed:  'slow', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#previous',
    pager:  '#pager',
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, el) {

         lastButIndex = idx;
         return '<a src="" class="test" id="but'+idx+'"  href="#"><img src="gfx/slideshowBut.jpg"></a>';
     }
    });
    currentBut = $("#but0");
    currentBut.children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowButPressed.jpg"); 


    $("#next").click(function(){    


        $(currentBut).children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowBut.jpg");
        $(currentBut).next().children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowButPressed.jpg");

        if($(currentBut).is(':last-child'))
        {
            $("#but0").children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowButPressed.jpg");
            currentBut = $("#but0");

        }
        else{
            currentBut = $(currentBut).next();
        }


    });

    $("#previous").click(function(){        
        $(currentBut).children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowBut.jpg");
        $(currentBut).prev().children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowButPressed.jpg"); 

        if($(currentBut).is(':first-child'))
        {               
            $("#but"+lastButIndex).children(1).attr("src","gfx/slideshowButPressed.jpg");
            currentBut = $("#but"+lastButIndex);
        }
        else{
            currentBut = $(currentBut).prev();
        }

    });
```

But I'm a bit stuck on how to adapt it now- any ideas would be greatly appreciated!Thanks.

Comment: Provide example (e.g. on jdfiddle.net) it will be so much easier to troubleshoot your code